# Error when calling selenium through xlwings

Tags: python, selenium, xlwings

When I directly call below function from the Python file main.py, it works and firefox shows up:

```
def show_firefox():
        webdriver.Firefox(r'c:\firefox_driver')
```

But when I tried to call this function through xlwings using below code，an AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process' shows up.

```
RunPython ("import main; main.show_firefox()")
```

And I have already tried to save the firefox driver to my win7 search path, but the error still existed.

python 64-bit 3.5, selenium 3.0.2 and xlwings 0.10.3 used in my project.

Below is the settings in xlwings:

```
PYTHON_WIN = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PythonLib\env\Scripts\pythonw.exe"
PYTHON_MAC = ""
PYTHON_FROZEN = ""
PYTHONPATH = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PythonLib"
UDF_MODULES = ""
```

Also I have changed my PYTHON_WIN to a full path, but the problem above still existed.

Comment: Problem resolved when upgraded selenium to 3.4.3

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely using a different python installation when running your script via `RunPython`.

Try to set the `PYTHON_WIN` setting to the full path of your interpreter and see if the problem still exists, see: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/vba.html#settings

Comment: When change PYTHON_WIN = "", it could work normally. Seems like the subprocess module used the wrong python env.